# Debugger not working: 'Socket Connection Error' after starting Debugger

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I tried to use the debugger in aptana studio 3. I'm using firefox 20.0..

I...
1.) ...deleted firebug before using Aptana.
2.) ...selected debug perspective in Aptana and started the debugger.
3.) ...installed the extension

4.) After 57% of progress: --> Error.

> > 'Launching Firefox- Internal Server' has encountered a problem
> >     Socket connection error- Please try shutting down and restarting your web browser, and then run 'debug' again.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? 
I could not find a solution... but a lot of people with the same problem

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found is to uninstall Firefox. Then launch debug and install firefox, firebug etc as requested. (during process  Firefox and Aptana have to be restarted couple of times. )
After that, you can debug for some time, until Aptana-FF bridge corrupts again, and FF needs to be uninstalled again.  (I wonder if there is some other IDE that is proper & supported)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things needed to debug in Aptana... I had this same issue and had to uninstall Git and then install [PortableGit](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.9.0-preview20140217.7z&can=2&q=portablegit) and then it worked fine.

I followed all the [instructions](http://aptana.com/products/studio3/download) for the Aptana  download on another machine it worked great.. I thought as I had Git on this machine, I wouldn't need PortableGit - I guessed wrong...

Make sure you add Git to your Path (On Windows - Click "Start"Rt-Click on Computer--> Properties--> Advanced System Settings --> Find "Path" and add  to the end of the existing string ";C:\<%System Program%>\Git;"  -- in my case C:\Program Files (x86)\Git -- if you're using a 64Bit version of windows C:\Program Files\GIT if 32Bit (add a semicolon prior to adding this.

Also Ruby & latest version of Java (even thou I hated adding it back due to it's faulty security... ) is needed (follow download instructions... the rest was optional for me.

FYI - I had to "Remove" the Add-On for Firebug prior to opening Aptana as it will install the appropriate version. After it does this, open Firefox and in Add-On's click More under firebug and set it to Not auto-update.

Good luck... let me know if that doesn't work...