# Socket connection error in Aptana debugging

Tags: debugging, firefox, firebug, aptana, aptana3

I am trying to debug some JavaScript code using Aptana Studio 3, build 3.6.1.201410201044, but I keep getting the error:

> Socket connection error. Please try shutting down and restarting your web browser, and then run 'debug' again.
> Accept timed out

After getting this error I found that others had the same problem and solved it by removing Firebug and reinstalling an earlier version of it. I decided to go farther than this, I freshly installed Firefox after deleting all previous plugins and extension data in 'AppData'. After this I installed Firebug 1.8.4 and the Aptana debugger plugin. However, whenever I run the debugger I continue to get this error.

Comment: Where did you read that this error can be solved by removing Firebug? Also note that Firebug 1.8.4 is an extremely outdated version and should not be used anymore.

Comment: Pretty much every question related to it on here has that as one of the solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532388/socket-connection-error-when-debugging-php-js-on-aptana-3 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854111/debugger-not-working-socket-connection-error-after-starting-debugger , https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/4014-cant-get-aptana-debugger-working

Comment: I am not using 1.8.4 because I want to, the Aptana Debugger plugin is not compatible with later versions.

Comment: A link to a forum in the first thread you posted [suggests](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3734) that it may be fixed by changing `;xdebug.remote_handler=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE` to `xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp` in the 'xdebug.conf' file.